# invalid syntax when using find_elemen_by_xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to find the element by xpath and constantly getting syntax error

It puts `^` mark before the colon in my xpath.

I'm generating the xpath in Chrome dev tools. Finding the element in html, right clicking it and selecting Copy xpath.

```
C:\>python ebcm_login.py
  File "ebcm_login.py", line 47
    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="j_idt51:j_idt55_body"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[1]/input")
                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

C:\>python ebcm_login.py
  File "ebcm_login.py", line 48
    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="menuForm:j_idt57"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]")
                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

C:\>python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:03:49) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="j_idt51:j_idt55_body"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[1]/input')
```

You are having overlapping quotation marks there. You're probably confusing it.
Here in your example you have placed double quotes inside existing double quotes.

for eg: `'"obanawev"'` is valid similarly `"'obanawev'"` is also valid but not `""obanawev""`

You can even give it inside triple quotes. Then you can use both double and single quote and overlapping of quotation marks can be avoided.

for e.g.:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//[@id="j_idt51:j_idt55_body"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[1]/input""")
```