# How to click on the Read more link from the first review within tripadvisor using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, tripadvisor

I am using selector gadget to get the xpath from the "read more" button from the first review on [this website](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g60982-d209422-Reviews-Hilton_Waikiki_Beach-Honolulu_Oahu_Hawaii.html)

This is the xpath it gave:

```
//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "Z", " " ))]
```

Here is the first part of the code I am using:

```
import selenium
import csv #This package lets us save data to a csv file
from selenium import webdriver #The Selenium package we'll need
import time #This package lets us pause execution for a bit
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

path_to_file = "/Users/user/Desktop/HotelReviews.csv"

pages_to_scrape = 3

url = "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g60982-d209422-Reviews-Hilton_Waikiki_Beach-Honolulu_Oahu_Hawaii.html"

# open the file to save the review
csvFile = open(path_to_file, 'a', encoding="utf-8")
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

for i in range(0, pages_to_scrape):
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("url")
    # give the DOM time to load
    time.sleep(2) 
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), 
    concat( " ", "Z", " " ))], 'Read more')]").click()
```

This is the error I get:

```
File "/var/folders/6c/jpl964752rv_72zjclrp_8ym0000gn/T/ipykernel_24978/2812702568.py", line 8
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "Z", " " ))], 'Read more')]").click()
                                                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Looks like it's the quotation marks that seems to be the issue.

So I followed [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236564/invalid-syntax-when-using-find-elemen-by-xpath). I tried making the code a variable, but it spit out the same error. I tried removing the extra quotes, same error. I tried removing the space between the quotes, same error.

I tried a different xpath, one for the whole review
`//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "F1", " " ))]`
Same error.

Then I tried adjusting the quotation marks on the first xpath

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), 
    concat( " ", "Z", " " ))]", "Read more")]).click()
```

results to the same error.

Answer (score 1):

To [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447) on the Read more link from the first review within [tripadvisor website](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g60982-d209422-Reviews-Hilton_Waikiki_Beach-Honolulu_Oahu_Hawaii.html) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g60982-d209422-Reviews-Hilton_Waikiki_Beach-Honolulu_Oahu_Hawaii.html')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Search reviews']//following::div[@data-test-target='HR_CC_CARD']//span[text()='Read more']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Read less]

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that while, for example `a[x="3"]` is a valid XPath expression, you can't put this in a Python string literal as `"a[x="3"]"` without escaping the quotes. I'm not a Python user but in most languages you would write `"a[x=\"3\"]"`; alternatively in XPath single and double quotes can be used interchangeably so you could write `"a[x='3']"`

Comment: I made adjustments to the quote placement, but it came up with the same error.